# System.Numerics.Vector<int> are only partially initialized

Tags: c#, .net-5, system.numerics

I'm trying to initialize a `Vector<int>` (to integrate with BepuPhysics but I think it's irrilevant).

The static property `System.Numerics.Vector<int>.Count` is equal to `8` on my system so I manually initialized an 8-elements array.

This is my code:

```
var handles = new []{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
var vector = new System.Numerics.Vector<int>(handles);
```

but only the first half of `vector` is initialized to the correct values:
[image: debugger screenshot]

Am I missing something obvious? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know the answer why it happens, but it looks like aghidini is right - it's a debugger problem, it displays just 4 values for a Vector instance.

Look at the following experiment:

[image]

Comment: Well, it seems there are no more ideas so I'll accept your answer, thanks!